# drupal 6 installation: redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-6

I am trying to install drupal6 on my localhost and the installation does not complete.
it gets stuck in after creating the database tables.

It redirects to `http://localhost/sie/install.php?locale=en&profile=default&op=start&id=105` and gives the below error.

In Firefox

`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

In Chrome

> This webpage has a redirect loop

I have tried enabling the cookies/adding localhost as an exception. please help me with this.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `.htaccess` file(s) or main config in regards to `Redirect` or `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @Qben Hi here is my default drupal6 .htaccess file            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: @Qben i think my issue is in my apache2.conf, because i tried installing drupal7 or drupal 8 it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my mysql configuration, I had given autocommit=0 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to make a huge datafile load faster then I forgot about it.

Because autocommit wouldnt happen the drupal install script would pile up all the transactions and cause a redirect loop.

When I commented the autocommit=0 line the problem went away.